# Export chainladder output in R to CSV file

Tags: r, csv, save

I have a problem with exporting the output that `chainladder` function from package `ChainLadder` creates. I want to export the output to CSV file or XLSX file.

I tried to save with function `save`, but when I open the CSV file there are some weird charachters.

My output looks like:

```
> chainladder(RAA)

$Models
$Models[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x + 0, data = data.frame(x = Triangle[, i], 
    y = Triangle[, i + 1]), weights = weights[, i]/Triangle[, 
    i]^delta[i])

Coefficients:
    x  
2.999  


 $Models[[2]]

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x + 0, data = data.frame(x = Triangle[, i], 
    y = Triangle[, i + 1]), weights = weights[, i]/Triangle[, 
    i]^delta[i])

Coefficients:
    x  
1.624  


$Models[[3]]

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x + 0, data = data.frame(x = Triangle[, i], 
    y = Triangle[, i + 1]), weights = weights[, i]/Triangle[, 
    i]^delta[i])

Coefficients:
    x  
1.271  


$Models[[4]]

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x + 0, data = data.frame(x = Triangle[, i], 
    y = Triangle[, i + 1]), weights = weights[, i]/Triangle[, 
    i]^delta[i])

Coefficients:
x  
1.172  


$Models[[5]]

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x + 0, data = data.frame(x = Triangle[, i], 
    y = Triangle[, i + 1]), weights = weights[, i]/Triangle[, 
    i]^delta[i])

Coefficients:
    x  
1.113  


$Models[[6]]

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x + 0, data = data.frame(x = Triangle[, i], 
    y = Triangle[, i + 1]), weights = weights[, i]/Triangle[, 
    i]^delta[i])

Coefficients:
    x  
1.042  


$Models[[7]]

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x + 0, data = data.frame(x = Triangle[, i], 
    y = Triangle[, i + 1]), weights = weights[, i]/Triangle[, 
    i]^delta[i])

Coefficients:
x  
1.033  


$Models[[8]]

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x + 0, data = data.frame(x = Triangle[, i], 
    y = Triangle[, i + 1]), weights = weights[, i]/Triangle[, 
    i]^delta[i])

Coefficients:
    x  
1.017  


$Models[[9]]

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x + 0, data = data.frame(x = Triangle[, i], 
    y = Triangle[, i + 1]), weights = weights[, i]/Triangle[, 
    i]^delta[i])

Coefficients:
    x  
1.009  



$Triangle
      dev
origin    1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
  1981 5012  8269 10907 11805 13539 16181 18009 18608 18662 18834
  1982  106  4285  5396 10666 13782 15599 15496 16169 16704    NA
  1983 3410  8992 13873 16141 18735 22214 22863 23466    NA    NA
  1984 5655 11555 15766 21266 23425 26083 27067    NA    NA    NA
  1985 1092  9565 15836 22169 25955 26180    NA    NA    NA    NA
  1986 1513  6445 11702 12935 15852    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
  1987  557  4020 10946 12314    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
  1988 1351  6947 13112    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
  1989 3133  5395    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
  1990 2063    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA

$delta
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

$weights
      dev
origin 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
  1981 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  1982 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 NA
  1983 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 NA NA
  1984 1  1  1  1  1  1  1 NA NA NA
  1985 1  1  1  1  1  1 NA NA NA NA
  1986 1  1  1  1  1 NA NA NA NA NA
  1987 1  1  1  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA
  1988 1  1  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
  1989 1  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
  1990 1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

attr(,"class")
[1] "ChainLadder"   "TriangleModel" "list"
```

Does anyone know how to save the upper output to CSV file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which part of the output list do you want to export?

Here's an example to store the element Triangle in a .csv-file:

```
library(ChainLadder)

cd <- chainladder(RAA)

write.csv(cd$Triangle, file = "stackoverflow/36154658/test.csv")
```

If you want to export every element you can either create different .csv-files or append the results with a loop to a single one. See:

```
?write.csv
```

**Edit:**
Maybe you just want to save the output of the print()-function in a text file?

```
cd <- chainladder(RAA)

sink("stackoverflow/36154658/test4.txt")
cd
sink()
unlink("test4.txt")
```

Comment: I want to export everything that functions returns. It works fine ofr Triangle part of the output.  But when I try to use `write.csv` for `cd$Models[1]` it returns an error `Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class ""lm"" to a data.frame`.  Do you maybe know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The error is quite speaking. The result of the function lm() is an object of class "lm". The function data.frame() that is called by write.csv() is not able to create an object of class "data.frame" from this object. Depending on what you would like to have as an result, you can transform the "lm"-object to other classes. Maybe `write.csv(as.character(cd$Models[[1]]), file = "stackoverflow/36154658/test2.csv")` is what you want.

Comment: Maybe it's even enough for you to have the calculated coefficient? `write.csv(cd$Models[[1]][1], file = "stackoverflow/36154658/test3.csv")`

Comment: I would like to export everything. The whole model, not only coefficients.

Comment: Maybe you just want to save the output of the print()-function in a text file?

Comment: Excellent! Exactly what I wanted. :)